# Matrix inverse usng linear system solver through cublas, cublasCreate exception or something else

Tags: algorithm, cuda, gpu, cublas, linear-equation

I'm trying to inverse a matrix using linear equation solver through cublas CUDA library.

The original equation is in form of:

```
Ax  = B  = I 

I - identity matrix 
A - The matrix I'm trying to inverse 
x - (hopefully) the inverse(A) matrix
```

I'd like to perform LU decomposition, receive the following:

```
LUx = B 

L - is a lower triangle matrix 
U - is a upper triangle matrix
```

Here is a good example who can show what I'm trying to do:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dza5JTvMpzk

For the sake of discussion, **let's assume I already have LU decomposition** of A. (A = LU). I'm trying to find the inverse  in a two steps series:

```
Ax = B = I 

LUx = B = I 

1st step:  Declare y: 

**Ly  = I** 

solve 1st linear equation 

2nd step, Solve the following linear equation

**Ux = y** 

find X = inverse(A) - *Bingo!@!*
```

For now I have no idea what am I doing wrong here. There might be two assumptions, either I'm not using cublas properly or cublas throws an exception for no reason.

See my code attached, there is Matlab code at the end:

```
     #include "cuda_runtime.h" 
     #include "device_launch_parameters.h"

     #include <stdio.h>


     //#include "cublas.h"
     #include "cublas_v2.h"


 int main()
 {

cudaError_t cudaStat;
cublasStatus_t stat;
cublasHandle_t handle;

//cublasInit();

stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    printf ("CUBLAS initialization failed\n");
    return -1;
}

unsigned int size = 3; 
// Allowcate device matrixes 
float* p_h_LowerTriangle; 
float* p_d_LowerTriangle; 

p_h_LowerTriangle = new float[size*size];
p_h_LowerTriangle[0] = 1.f;  
p_h_LowerTriangle[1] = 0.f;
p_h_LowerTriangle[2] = 0.f;
p_h_LowerTriangle[3] = 2.56f;
p_h_LowerTriangle[4] = 1.f; 
p_h_LowerTriangle[5] = 0.f; 
p_h_LowerTriangle[6] = 5.76f; 
p_h_LowerTriangle[7] = 3.5f;
p_h_LowerTriangle[8] = 1.f;

float* p_h_UpperTriangle; 
float* p_d_UpperTriangle; 

p_h_UpperTriangle = new float[size*size];
p_h_UpperTriangle[0] = 25.f;  
p_h_UpperTriangle[1] = 5.f;
p_h_UpperTriangle[2] = 1.f;
p_h_UpperTriangle[3] = 0.f;
p_h_UpperTriangle[4] = -4.8f; 
p_h_UpperTriangle[5] = -1.56f; 
p_h_UpperTriangle[6] = 0.f; 
p_h_UpperTriangle[7] = 0.f;
p_h_UpperTriangle[8] = 0.7f;

float* p_h_IdentityMatrix; 
float* p_d_IdentityMatrix; 

p_h_IdentityMatrix = new float[size*size];
p_h_IdentityMatrix[0] = 1.f;  
p_h_IdentityMatrix[1] = 0.f;
p_h_IdentityMatrix[2] = 0.f;
p_h_IdentityMatrix[3] = 0.f;
p_h_IdentityMatrix[4] = 1.f; 
p_h_IdentityMatrix[5] = 0.f; 
p_h_IdentityMatrix[6] = 0.f; 
p_h_IdentityMatrix[7] = 0.f;
p_h_IdentityMatrix[8] = 1.f;

cudaMalloc ((void**)&p_d_LowerTriangle, size*size*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc ((void**)&p_d_UpperTriangle, size*size*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc ((void**)&p_d_IdentityMatrix, size*size*sizeof(float));


float* p_d_tempMatrix; 
cudaMalloc ((void**)&p_d_tempMatrix, size*size*sizeof(float));


stat = cublasSetMatrix(size,size,sizeof(float),p_h_LowerTriangle,size,p_d_LowerTriangle,size);
stat = cublasSetMatrix(size,size,sizeof(float),p_h_UpperTriangle,size,p_d_UpperTriangle,size);
stat = cublasSetMatrix(size,size,sizeof(float),p_h_IdentityMatrix,size,p_d_IdentityMatrix,size);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// 1st phase - solve Ly = b 
const float alpha  = 1.f;

// Function solves the triangulatr linear system with multiple right hand sides, function overrides b as a result 
stat =  cublasStrsm(handle,
    cublasSideMode_t::CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, 
    cublasFillMode_t::CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER,
    cublasOperation_t::CUBLAS_OP_N,
    CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT,
    size,
    size,
    &alpha,
    p_d_LowerTriangle,
    size,
    p_d_IdentityMatrix,
    size);

////////////////////////////////////
// TODO: printf 1st phase the results 
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaMemcpy(p_h_IdentityMatrix,p_d_IdentityMatrix,size*size*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(p_h_UpperTriangle,p_d_UpperTriangle,size*size*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(p_h_LowerTriangle,p_d_LowerTriangle,size*size*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

stat =cublasGetMatrix(size,size,sizeof(float),p_d_IdentityMatrix,size,p_h_IdentityMatrix,size);
stat =cublasGetMatrix(size,size,sizeof(float),p_d_UpperTriangle,size,p_h_UpperTriangle,size);
stat =cublasGetMatrix(size,size,sizeof(float),p_d_LowerTriangle,size,p_h_LowerTriangle,size);

////////////////////////////////////

// 2nd phase - solve Ux = b
stat =  cublasStrsm(handle,
    cublasSideMode_t::CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, 
    cublasFillMode_t::CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER,
    cublasOperation_t::CUBLAS_OP_N,
    CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT,
    size,
    size,
    &alpha,
    p_d_UpperTriangle,
    size,
    p_d_IdentityMatrix,
    size);

// TODO print the results 
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

////////////////////////////////////
cudaMemcpy(p_h_IdentityMatrix,p_d_IdentityMatrix,size*size*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(p_h_UpperTriangle,p_d_UpperTriangle,size*size*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(p_h_LowerTriangle,p_d_LowerTriangle,size*size*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
////////////////////////////////////

cublasDestroy(handle);
//cublasShutdown();

cudaFree(p_d_LowerTriangle);
cudaFree(p_d_UpperTriangle);
cudaFree(p_d_IdentityMatrix);

free(p_h_LowerTriangle);
free(p_h_UpperTriangle);
free(p_h_IdentityMatrix);


return 0;
}
```

Matlab code - works perfect:

```
  clear all

   UpperMatrix  = [ 25 5 1  ;  0 -4.8  -1.56  ;  0 0 0.7 ]

   LowerMatrix  = [1 0 0 ; 2.56 1 0 ; 5.76 3.5 1  ]

   IdentityMatrix = eye(3)

    % 1st phase solution 
    otps1.LT = true;
    y = linsolve(LowerMatrix,IdentityMatrix,otps1)

    %2nd phase solution 
    otps2.UT = true;
    y = linsolve(UpperMatrix,y,otps2)
```

### MATLAB output

UpperMatrix =

```
25.0000    5.0000    1.0000
      0   -4.8000   -1.5600
      0         0    0.7000
```

LowerMatrix =

```
1.0000         0         0
2.5600    1.0000         0
5.7600    3.5000    1.0000
```

IdentityMatrix =

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
```

y =

```
 1.0000         0         0
-2.5600    1.0000         0
 3.2000   -3.5000    1.0000
```

y =

```
 0.0476   -0.0833    0.0357
-0.9524    1.4167   -0.4643
 4.5714   -5.0000    1.4286
```

UpperMatrix =

```
25.0000    5.0000    1.0000
      0   -4.8000   -1.5600
      0         0    0.7000
```

LowerMatrix =

```
1.0000         0         0
2.5600    1.0000         0
5.7600    3.5000    1.0000
```

IdentityMatrix =

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
```

y =

```
 1.0000         0         0
-2.5600    1.0000         0
 3.2000   -3.5000    1.0000

>> 
>> 
>> 
>> Inverse_LU_UT
```

UpperMatrix =

```
25.0000    5.0000    1.0000
      0   -4.8000   -1.5600
      0         0    0.7000
```

LowerMatrix =

```
1.0000         0         0
2.5600    1.0000         0
5.7600    3.5000    1.0000
```

IdentityMatrix =

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
```

y =

```
 1.0000         0         0
-2.5600    1.0000         0
 3.2000   -3.5000    1.0000
```

y =

```
 0.0476   -0.0833    0.0357
-0.9524    1.4167   -0.4643
 4.5714   -5.0000    1.4286
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong here, I suspect the cublasCreate  operation. Every time I hit the  command:

```
  cublasStatus_t stat;
  cublasHandle_t handle;
  stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
```

stat and handle variables are both valid.

But VS10 output several error messages specified the following:

> First chance exception at 0x... microsoft C++ exception cudaError_enum at memory location 0x...

Some may say it's an internal cublas error message, handled by the library itself.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the absolute shortest complete example which shows the problem. Three lines of code taken out of context and an incomplete error message isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: I'll  give a whole example  shortly

Comment: Is that really the *shortest* example you can offer showing the cublas runtime exception your original question was asking about?

Comment: LOL started by solving linear equation using LU decomposition, couldn't make it run properly yet... this is killing me

Comment: I might have some confusion between row and column leading matrix, not sure about it yet

Comment: It is still completely unclear what you are asking about. Is it the runtime exception or something to do with the results? Your question started out looking like it was the former, but now it is the latter.

Comment: Answer solved on CUDA forum [Here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/547486/cuda-programming-and-performance/matrix-inverse-usng-linear-system-solver-through-cublas-cublascreate-exception-or-something-else/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what, cuBlas stores matrix in column-major way, but Matlab and C use row-major way.

Rearrange your initialization and run.  Result should be good.